Prove that the convolution of the signals and its time reversal is an odd signal.
Suppose signal $g(t)$ is obtained by time reversal of signal $f(t)$ for all times $t$. Prove that the convolution of the signals $f$ and $g$ is an odd signal.
 My attempt at proof 
Given: $g(t)=f(-t)\forall t\in \mathbb R$
To prove: $(f*g)(t)$ is odd.
Now, $(f*g)(t):={\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} }f(\tau)f(\tau-t)d\tau$. Taking Laplace transform on both sides, 
$$F(s)G(s)=\cases {F^2 (s) \text{ if }f(t) \text{ is even}\\ -F^2(s) \text{ if }f(t) \text{ is odd}}$$
Since, 
$$\mathcal L(f(-t))=\cases {F (s) \text{ if }f(t) \text{ is even}\\ -F(s) \text{ if }f(t) \text{ is odd}}$$
This conclusion I came to after investigation of a number of odd and even functions like $\sin t, \cos t, t^2, t,...$ etc. However, the above isn't true exactly for sums of functions like $\sin t+\cos t$ or $t+t^2$. Yet it will be enough to prove that $\mathcal L^{-1}(\pm F^2(s))$ is odd. The last thing that I get is that $F^2(s)$ is an even function.
